# How To Log When Invalid Bearer Token Is Sent To Backend

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, jwt

I have a Jhipster built backend and am looking to log when an invalid authentication Bearer token is sent with a request.

Currently using Postman I can send a valid token to get information I need and that is logged like so:

```
2020-10-14 10:11:37.591 DEBUG 4132 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@77674d5d5 pairs: {GET /auth/realms/p
latform-development/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/jwk-set+json}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.7}{Host: sso.eva-int.c
om}{Connection: keep-alive}
2020-10-14 10:11:37.630 DEBUG 4132 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@2527b0a66 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200
 OK}{Connection: keep-alive}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Content-Type: application/json}{Content-Length: 1703}{Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 17:11:36 GMT}
2020-10-14 10:11:37.649 DEBUG 4132 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] jdk.event.security                       : X509Certificate: Alg:SHA256withRSA, Serial:17251f0f612, Subjec
t:CN=platform-development, Issuer:CN=platform-development, Key type:RSA, Length:2048, Cert Id:1603036153, Valid from:5/26/20, 10:02 AM, Valid until:5/26/30, 10:04
 AM
```

When I send an invalid token I get back a response with a status of 401 and headers saying 'invalid_token' which is perfectly fine, but nothing is logged in the application.

It seems like the code that handles this comes from Spring Security dependency. Is there any way to have it log out more information?

Comment: Which authentication type did you select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security has its own logging, you just need to enable it.

Put the following in your application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

This is the same for most other Spring modules as well.

OR

Try setting the property in your logging configuration, e.g. logback.

Here is the application.yml version:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

Comment: I do not see any additional output when including that in my application.yml. Using ```@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)``` in Security configuration gives me a Security filter chain output on all requests but still no logging for invalid token besides that.

Comment: What you did that is different thing, it wont enable your spring security logs. Follow the below link for better understanding of spring logging. [Spring logiging tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging)

Comment: So when I run the application with argument ```-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG``` then I get the extra logging I am looking for. Putting that in my application.yml does not give the output though.

Comment: This ended up working but I was putting it in the wrong application.yml. Thanks!